# Flutter Firebase callbacks are not fired on iOS 13, but work fine on Android

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I'm currently developing a flutter app, when I've experienced the following:

On Android, everything works as expected. If the app is in foreground, `onMessage` is called, `onLaunch` and so on if the app was in background.

On iOS (13), none of the callbacks are called. The notification arrives, is showing the correct icon, text and title, when I click on the notification the app opens, but none of the callbacks are fired. If the app is already in foreground, no Notification is shown (as expected), but `onMessage` isn't called either.

Here is the payload I'm sending:

```
{
  "data": {
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  "to": "RECEIVER",
  "notification": {
    "sound": "default",
    "title": "Title",
    "body": "Message"
  }
}
```

Flutter code:

```dart
firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    log.info('Firebase::onMessage: $message');

    _handleMessage(message);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    log.info('Firebase::onResume: $message');

    _handleMessage(message);
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    log.info('Firebase::onLaunch: $message');

    _handleMessage(message);
  },
);
```

AppDelegate.swift:

I've tried to run the app with and without the following lines

```swift
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
```

I have enabled push notifications, background fetch and remote notifications in the capabilities tab in XCode.

I am running Flutter 1.12.13 (beta channel), however I also tried to run the app with flutter stable, which resulted in the same behavior.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale en-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.3 at /usr/local/bin/flutter
    • Framework revision 57f2df76d7 (3 days ago), 2019-12-05 21:23:21 -0800
    • Engine revision ac9391978e
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/martin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Users/martin/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/191.6010548/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.2.1, Build version 11B500
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Users/martin/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/191.6010548/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 40.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/martin/Applications/JetBrains Toolbox/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
With ios 13, the guide on Readme.md is wrong.
Check 2 things.

1. removed code

   ```swift
   if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
   [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = (id) self;
   }
   ```
2. check if you have "flutter_local_notifications" library
   Then, remove it.

---

Currently, I know this is plugin bug, caused by ios 13 update.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1041
Please thumbs up for this issue.